# Biblical attribution of intelligence and feelings to the human heart

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hashkafah-philosophy, science, soul

Traditionally, the human heart was considered the residence of the animated soul and numerous Biblical passages refer to that ancient belief:

> "You shall love the LORD your God with all your heart..."
> "And God said to him in the dream, “I knew that you did this with a blameless heart"
> "... so that you do not forget the things that you saw with your own eyes and so that they do not fade from your heart as long as you live"
> "Assuredly, thus said GOD: Because you have deemed your heart equal to a god’s"

Evidently, the heart is but a blood pump and has nothing to do with spirituality or intellect. Moses should have known this and use different, more physiologically correct allegories.

IIRC, after [Galen's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galen) (c. 200AD) discovery of the nervous system, sages included the brain (מח) in the relation with the soul alongside the hears and the liver (*earliest source needed*).

Why does the Torah see the heart as the source of the mind and feelings as opposed to the head/the brain?

Comment: "Moses should have known this and use different, more physiologically correct allegories." Why? I know it and still speak of a "broken heart" after major emotional losses.

Comment: The wicked love God only with their lips, kidney and liver, not heart and soul.

Comment: "Leiv", like the English word "heart" can also refer to a geometric point. As in, "the heart of the matter." Heart was associated with mind because it is a critical organ near the middle of the body. The geometry made the heart a good and natural metaphor. It would be normal to assume it was literally true as well, but the literal biological truth wasn't the point. The point was to place a person's thoughts and feelings at the center of their being.

Comment: Because the heart is where you feel the emotions that is caused by the thoughts in your brain.

Comment: @DoubleAA A good point, 1. since the heart responses quickly to emotional stimuli, it was considered the dwelling of the anima (נפש) and hence the source of emotions in practically all ancient cultures. 2. Unless you rely on "דברה התורה כלשון בנ"א" namely that Moses used Egyptian idioms to familiarize the Hebrews with the Torah, I would expect him to use more correct analogies.

Comment: It is not clear that the central nervous system as a whole is not the repository of thoughts and feelings, e.g. see https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2017/05/spider-brain-spider-brain/528153/

Answer (score -2):

Ibn Ezra wrote to Exodus 23:25 (commentary) that the soul (the intellect) is housed in the brain. Although the ruach resides in the heart.

The term "heart" in the Bible is a metaphor for the mind. When the Torah says to love G-d with all your heart this means mind.

The ibn Ezra explains:

> “[A]ll the precepts written in the Torah, transmitted by tradition, or
> enacted by the rabbis aim in perfecting the heart [mind]. This is the
> case even though most of the commandments are observed by action or
> speech.”[1]

[1] From Israel Drazin's article [here](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/abraham-ibn-ezras-explanations-of-the-biblical-laws/).

Comment: Where is the last quote from?

Comment: @mbloch See the Ibn Ezra commentary to Exodus 23:25.

Comment: Well I read it three times on Sefaria and didn't find the second quote there. Did you check inside or are you quoting from a secondary source?

Comment: Oh I see now. You must be quoting for a secondary source because your last quote is NOT from Exodus 23:25. It is from Ibn Ezra on Deuteronomy 6:5. You should edit, and in general you should check your sources.

Comment: @mbloch Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: No your edit is not correct. The first quote is from Exodus 23:25. It is the second quote which is from Deut 6:5. Again please check sources yourself

Comment: @mbloch Thank you. I edited it correctly now.

Comment: If you are quoting from a secondary source, and especially if you are using their translations, please cite your source. Also, I don't see that in ibn Ezra's comments on Deut 6:5.

Comment: @magicker72 the first quote is from my source. The last one is from RNS.

Comment: @TurkHill I'm not sure what RNS stands for, but a Google search shows that the last quotation is found verbatim in an [article by Israel Drazin](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/abraham-ibn-ezras-explanations-of-the-biblical-laws/). Is that your source?

Comment: @magicker72 I was referring to [this Ibn Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Deuteronomy.6.5.2?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) which refers to the second para in the answer. But like you I strongly believe one needs to check sources inside oneself before writing an answer

Comment: @magicker72 Yes. He is a good source. He is right in about everything he says. Rabbi Drazin is a true scholar. Anything you read from him will be well worth it.

Comment: @TurkHill If you're quoting someone, you should say that *in your answer*.

Comment: @magicker72 Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @TurkHill You've used the site long enough to have done that yourself.

Comment: @magicker72 In any case, I appreciate your edits.